# Extract Maven Dependency Version from POM

Tags: java, maven

Given that I have Dependency groupId and artifactId, how do I extract the version for this dependency from the pom.xml file?

Example: I want to be able to extract the dependency version below if I query using the artifactId and groupId.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

I want to assign the version to a global environment variable i.e. DEP_VERSION=1.6

Comment: Is there a maven plugin or Bash commands I can run to extract the dependency version based on the artifactID I pass in?

Answer (score 0):

It is an xml. 
Trivially you could make a parsing of the file.

Comment: Ultimately, what I'm looking for is set environment varialbe to the dependency version based on the artifactid/groupid DEP_VERSION=1.6

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Maven Dependency Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html):

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=com.google.guava:guava
```

It will output something like:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MyProject 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ project-server ---
[INFO] com.company.project:project-server:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:19.0:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.016 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-04-06T16:58:55+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/437M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I want to be able to set as an environment variable i.e. DEP_VERSION=$(mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=com.google.guava:guava) that won't work